Universal property of HNN extensions
The amalgamated free product of groups can be defined as a certain presentation; or, one can define it as a pushout where the morphisms are embeddings. I was wondering if the definition of an HNN extension can be given in terms of some sort of universal property as well?

Yes, but not in the category of groups. HNN extensions are a $2$-colimit or homotopy colimit in the $2$-category of groupoids. Specifically they are coinserters; you can see this stated at the nLab page.
Most people don't really want to think about $2$-categories so this language is not very common but it really is the correct universal property and also explains the relationship to algebraic topology. Semidirect products are also a $2$-colimit called the homotopy quotient and this can be used to give a $2$-categorical approach to understanding their representation theory, for example.

Without categorical language:
let $A$ be a group and $f:B\to C$ be an isomorphism between two subgroups of $A$.
Consider the following universal property: $G$ is a group, $t\in G$ and $u:A\to G$ is a homomorphism such that $u(f(b))=tu(b)t^{-1}$ for every $b\in B$, and for every group $H$, every $s\in H$ and homomorphism $v:A\to H$ such that $v(f(b))=sv(b)s^{-1}$ for every $b\in B$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi: G\to H$ such that $\phi(t)=s$ and $\phi(u(a))=v(a)$ for every $a\in A$.
It is essentially formal that such $(G,t)$ exists and is unique up to unique isomorphism (of pairs consisting of a group with an element). Basic HNN theory tells us a little more: that $u:A\to G$ is injective, that there exists a unique homomorphism $G\to\mathbf{Z}$ mapping $t$ to $1$ and $u(A)$ to zero, etc.
